# How to dynamically modify <div> tag in Django for loop using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a Django template which iterates through records, and I want to modify the div tag based on the average value calculate from the element of the each record. And I try to do it in the way below, but it's not working. Any idea how to dynamically modify  tag inside Django for loop using JavaScript?

```html
{% for resource in result_basic  %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var loc_rating = "{{resource.loc_rating}}";
    var fac_rating = "{{resource.fac_rating}}";
    var tran_rating ="{{resource.tran_rating}}";
    var property_avg = (Number(loc_rating)+Number(fac_rating)+Number(tran_rating))/3;

    document.getElementsByClassName('pratings-{{forloop.counter}}').innerHTML=property_avg;

    </script>
    <p>Property Ratings: <div class="pratings-{{forloop.counter}}"></div></p>
    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You need to carry out all the arithmetic inside the view and then you may pass the result to the template as a context variable.

Comment: Why would you use Javascript for this?

Comment: @art06 Yes you are right, but the result_basic object is a queryset which comes from the database, so I'm calculating something without modifying the table in the database.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to calculate something without modify result_basic which is a queryset object comes from the models.py, it seems javaScript is a good way to manipulate the html tag.